# Weierstrass product expression for Klein's j-invariant

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, infinite-product

The first sentence of @ccorn's [answer to a previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466975/elements-of-sl2-mathbbz-which-fix-roots-of-kleins-absolute-invariant-j) was:

“Because of the modular symmetries of $j(\tau)$,
the zeros of $j(\tau)$ are precisely the $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$-transforms
of the fundamental-domain zero $\zeta_3=\mathrm{e}^{2\pi\mathrm{i}/3}$.”

To what extent can $j(\tau)$ be written as an infinite product over those zeros?, something like this:

$$j(\tau)\stackrel{?}{=}u(\tau)\cdot\prod_{A\in\mathbf{SL}(2,\mathbf{Z})}\left[1-\frac{\tau}{A(e^{2\pi i/3})}\right]^{3}$$

And,  if such an expression were valid, what would $u(\tau)$ be?