# Modular forms and functions

Tags: functional-analysis

What exactly does a modular function mean?

Is it just a graph in Q1 and Q2 or does it have to satisfy any other properties?

Comment: I don't know what Q1 and Q2 are. Have you studied analytic function theory? If not, it won't be easy to explain modular forms and functions to you.

Comment: NO. And Q's are the quadrants in x-y plane

Comment: I was going through Hardy-collected papers and found out the same.

Comment: The x-y plane is for graphing real-valued functions of a real variable. Modular forms are complex-valued functions of a complex variable. So there's a bit more to it than graphs in the x-y plane.

Comment: So would a book on complex variables help me?

Comment: If you are ready to read a book on complex variables, that would be a good place to start. But I still have no feeling for where you are, mathematically.

Answer (score 3):

(this isn't intended to be encyclopedic, just comprehensive enough to give someone starting out some good intuitive pointers)

So, think about the standard trigonometric functions -- they're symmetric by a translation of integer multiples of $2\pi$ -- you slide it along and you get the same thing back, $\sin(z)=\sin(2k\pi+z)$ for all integer $k$. Skipping over elliptics which are doubly periodic for the moment (but you're going to probably want to come back to them later), the transformations of the plane which leave (what is arguably the keystone of modular functions) the Klein j-invariant $j(\tau)$ unchanged are given by the [modular group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group) $\mathbf{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$

$$j(\tau)=j((a\tau+b)/(c\tau+d))$$

Where $ab-cd=1$

(\frac doesn't appear to behaving appropriately)

$j(\tau)$ is [meromorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function), and is only defined for the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$. Here is a [domain colored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) picture of $j(\tau)$:

[image]

$\mathbf{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is a discrete group and it's a subgroup of $\mathbf{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, and by [making judicious choices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338332/visualizing-functions-invariant-or-almost-under-modular-transformation), one can [*see* how $j(\tau)$ is invariant with respect to $\mathbf{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvQ7e2AiE2g).

“Every rational function of $j(\tau)$ is a modular function, and every modular function can be expressed as a rational function of $j(\tau)$ ” (Apostol quoted in [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KleinsAbsoluteInvariant.html), slightly modified)

Modular *forms* are only symmetric up to a subgroup of $\mathbb{SL}(2,\mathbf{Z})$ A good one to start with is the  [Dedekind eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function)

It is difficult to write a brief summary about where in mathematics modular forms and functions occur because they occur in many places related to number theory, complex analysis, and others, and have a tendency to satisfy many identities, some [quite unexpected and puzzling (moonshine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_moonshine)

There are many online resources about modular functions and forms:

- [the LMFDB, the database of L-functions, modular forms](http://www.lmfdb.org/)
- [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) has excellent support for modular functions and forms
- [Modular Functions and Modular Forms](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/mf.html) by J. S. Milne
- [The Modular Forms Database](http://modular.math.washington.edu/Tables/) also by William Stein.

Comment: That was helpful.